# Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'zones', Joining 3 database tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql

My database tables

zones [ id  zone  zone_manager_email]

cities [ id  city  zone_id ]

store[id name store_no   city_id]

I have these 3 tables, I tried to inner join them , but my code is not working.

```
 SELECT zones.zone, zones.zone_manager_email,store.store_id
 FROM zones,store
 INNER JOIN zones on zones.id = cities.zone_id
 INNER JOIN store ON store.city_id = city.id
```

Comment: Why are you joining each table twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you never really reference the cities table, then you seem a bit consfused over the difference between different ways of doing this.

from a, b WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 
vs
from a inner join b on a.cool1 = b.col1.

Try this one :).

```
SELECT zones.zone, zones.zone_manager_email,store.store_id
FROM zones
INNER JOIN cities ON zones.id = cities.zone_id
INNER JOIN store ON store.city_id = city.id
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'city.id' in 'on clause' now its shows like this

Comment: I didn't proofread your code enough. Try to figure it out by yourself and if it doesn't work switch from singular form to plural form on city :)

Comment: thank you, it was my mistake , it works now.